# need some advice on my database design

Tags: database-design, cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakePHP 1.26.
I am going to build a very simple forum on localhost.
Here is the conceptual design for the Database:

Tables:
User {user_id, name, date}
Topic {post_id, title, content, date}
Reply {post_id, content, date}
Quote {quote_post_id, post_type, post_id}

A User may have many Topic
A User may have many Reply
A Topic may have many Quote
A Reply may have many Quote
(Both Topic and Reply may be quoted once or many times)

Please help and advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User {id, name, logname, password}

Topic {id, title, content, date, user_id}

Reply {id, content, date, topic_id, user_id}

I'm not sure about `Quote`... I do not know why that does not fit under `Reply`.

Comment: Just as Topic has one user and Reply has one user, Quote probably also had one user -- and possibly one Topic as well, if only Topics can be quoted. If true, Add user_id and post_id to table Quote.

Comment: My impression is that Quotes are like references.  It's a many-many association between posts.  The complication is that apparently either a Topic or Reply can reference either a Topic or Reply.

Answer (score 1):

You definitly want to introduce a field named id, as it is somewhat redundant to name a field `user_id` when it is the id field in table `users`. In addition to that cakephp treats some fields as *automagic*. *Automagic* means that cakephp can identify foreign-keys without you - the developer- having to specify them explicitly. But in order to have cakephp help you with *automagic* you have to stick to a few *conventions*. One of these conventions, which once learned are quite handy, is that foreign keys are automagically detected, once you name them YOUR_MODEL_NAME_IN_SINGULAR_HERE_id;
e.g.: An author *hasMany* posts, a post *belongsTo* an author (*). In this case you can store the foreign key as `autor_id` in the table `posts`. Later when you use the `cake bake` script or scaffolding feature, you will come to understand the power of convention!

Another thing I noticed in your post is, that it could be you are going to miss that in cakephp relationships are established **bi-directionally**. This means you don't only work with a single *hasMany* definition, but at the same time in the other direction with a *belongsTo* definition.

Therefore I suggest you rephrase your statements in order to implement later cooler.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to try taking thelost's answer in a different direction:

User {id, name, logname, password}

Post {id, title, content, date, parent_post_id, user_id}

Quote {post_id, quoted_post_id}

In this model, a post is a topic if parent_post_id is NULL.  Replies will have parent_post_id set to the id of their topic.  (Or you could allow a tree structure of replies.)

Warning: My experience is in normal SQL.  I don't know how things work in cakephp, so someone else will have to help you with that.